# React axios form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some problems with my React app. I'm trying to get axios request, but get request is never giving any errors or anything, just doesn't work.
It's giving an input value in the console but in network, there is no request.
This is how code looks like.

This is index.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'util/Api';
import ProductSearch from "./ProductSearch";


import IntlMessages from "util/IntlMessages";

class SamplePage extends Component {
    onSearchSubmit(url){
        axios.get('scrap', {
            url: {query: url}
        });
    }
    render(){
        console.log(this);
        return (
            <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: '10px'}}>
                <ProductSearch onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
            </div>
            );
    }
}

export default SamplePage;
```

This is ProductSearch.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, Input} from "antd";

const Search = Input.Search;

class ProductSearch extends React.Component{
    state = { url: '' };

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render(){
        return (
                <Card className="gx-card" title="Search Box">
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                  <Search
                    placeholder="Product Link: ex. http://www.aliexpres.com/item/name/id.html"
                    onSearch={value => console.log(value)}
                    enterButton="Submit"
                  />
                  </form>
                </Card>
            );
        }
}

export default ProductSearch;
```

And util/Api (axios)

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:8000/api/`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
});
```

Comment: bind or arrow `onSearchSubmit`, use `this.props.onSubmit()` in `onFormSubmit` - no axios response handling

Answer (score 1):

In `ProductSearch.js` you are not calling the `onSubmit` props method passed by `IntlMessages`  component. Try calling the `onSubmit()` method inside `onFormSubmit()` method

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, Input} from "antd";

const Search = Input.Search;

class ProductSearch extends React.Component{
    state = { url: '' };

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.url)
    }

    handleOnChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value });

    render(){
        return (
                <Card className="gx-card" title="Search Box">
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                  <Search
                    placeholder="Product Link: ex. http://www.aliexpres.com/item/name/id.html"
                    onSearch={value => console.log(value)}
                    enterButton="Submit"
                    name="url"
                  />
                  </form>
                </Card>
            );
        }
}

export default ProductSearch;
```

Also try to changing `url` to `params`

```
onSearchSubmit(url){
    axios.get('scrap', {
        params: {query: url}
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed it like this but still noting.